# Using std::distance to initialise const members goes awry sometimes

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, visual-studio-2015

I'm a bit confused by an error I just ran into. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I am running into inconsistent behaviour. I've cut out the code from the project it was in and recreated the behaviour, allow me to walk you through the code:

```
template <typename Ty>
struct Simple_Array
{
    Ty* data;
    const size_t size;

    Simple_Array(size_t size) :
        size(size),
        data(new Ty[size])
    {
    }

    virtual ~Simple_Array() {
        delete[] data;
    }
};
```

As you can see I'm using a simple wrapper for a c array in my code, I wanted to use a c array for the purpose of self teaching, hence not using something like std::vector or std::array. While using this I found need for a constructor that takes a first and last iterator over any other container, so I decided to use std::distance(first, last) to calculate the size.

```
    template <class It>
    Simple_Array(It first, It last) :
        size(std::distance(first, last)),
        data(new Ty[size])
    {
        for (int i = 0; first != last; ++first, ++i)
            data[i] = *first;
    }
```

Now, when I use this constructor size is initialised to crazy large values such as 3435973836. Why? This is particularly confusing because the following code works just fine:

```
    template <class It>
    Simple_Array(It first, It last) :
        Simple_Array(std::distance(first, last))
    {
        for (int i = 0; first != last; ++first, ++i)
            data[i] = *first;
    }
```

To test this I wrote the following main function:

```
int main() {
    auto list = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    try {
        Simple_Array<int>(list.begin(), list.end());
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Failed." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I took a peek at the disassembly but I haven't figured out what the issue is. The good news is because I have a workaround I don't need an answer to this to keep working on my project, but I'd still really like to know what is going wrong here.

I pastedbin'd the whole file here: [pastebin.com/ebNrsLaB](http://pastebin.com/ebNrsLaB)

Comment: I answered what is the cause of the problem. On a side note, your second version (one with delegating constructor) is actually nicer.

Comment: @SergeyA Yea I take your point. Nice to know where the misunderstanding came from however!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow! It the first time in my life when I actually see a point in notorious gcc warning regarding order of initializion.

In particular, class members are initialized in the order they are defined in your class, not in the order they are listed in constructor initialization list. Since your `Ty* data;` is defined before `size`, it is initialized (allocated) before size is set to the actual value - with the random value from uninitialized size.

To fix the issue, make sure you define size before data in the class.

Comment: Or they could rename the parameter so it is not the same as the class member and then use the parameter instead of the member.

Comment: @NathanOliver, this is obviously another option.

Comment: Thanks! I should have figured it out from the step through, now that I think about it the step through went to initialise data first, then size, but never got to size due to throwing an exception. So I was still reading the uninitialised size.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good thinking, as per SergeyA's suggestion, I'm going with the delegating constructor due to it being a better way to design the constructor, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Simple_Array
{
    Ty* data;            // (1)
    const size_t size;   // (2)

    Simple_Array(size_t size) :
        size(size),         // (2)
        data(new Ty[size])  // (1)
    {
    }
```

The member variables are initialized in the order they are declared in the struct, **not** in the order you write them in the constructor initializer list.

The compiler ought to warn you about this.

Comment: MSVC doesn't have this warning.

Comment: GCC and Intel C++ Compiler do, as should be.

Comment: My personal problem with this warning is that it is too generic. Just changing the order is most often harmless. Compiler it least should do a decent attempt to figure out if the order matters - it is fully equipped to do so.

Comment: Interesting, odd that MSVC doesn't warn you about this, thanks!